# How to remotely access a ubuntu server on a virtual machine?

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualbox, windows-10

New user here, I'm using Windows 10 and I want to access my Ubuntu Server that is in a virtual machine on the same computer. I'm trying to use puTTY and, by ssh, putting the server IP but without success.
I'm using VirtualBox, configured in NAT. By `nmap localhost` it says ssh service is open.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hi Lorena!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  We're going to need a bit more information.  What virtual environment are you using?  Have you configured the virtual network in NAT, bridge, host, or local mode?  How have you tested that the ssh port is open?  Please include the commands you ran and the output of those commands so we can see.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: What setting is the virtual network adapter at? Is it on NAT or Bridged? If you set it on Bridged, it gets a dedicated IP address from DHCP and you can ssh it directly to it using that address.

Comment: What settings have you put into Preferences -> Network -> NAT Network -> Properties and "Port Forwarding"?  Are you able to put in a screenshot of these two windows into your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with this until recently, where I found a long-term solution where I could pernamently save my connection settings in PuTTY and WinTCP for convenience.

Personally, I have configured my VirtualBox machine to use two networks:

- [NAT for access to the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt7Mh.png)
- [Host-Only Adapter to communicate with the VM via PuTTY and WinSCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLSV7.png)

In the VirtualBox Manager, I've made just one change to the "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adaptor" - disabling the DHCP server. By default this should leave you with a [configuration like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E98Aj.png), assuming the IP address defaults haven't been changed.

Within the virtual machine itself, you need to do two things:

- Set your IPv4 address for this host-only network manually to `192.168.56.10`, subnet of `192.168.56.0/24`, and no setting for other components where applicable (i.e. gateway).
- Ensure that `openssh-server` is installed and running. Use `sudo service ssh status` to check if its installed and running.
- Check that your firewall is either disabled or (preferably) enabled and configured to allow for ssh connections. If you are using ufw you can allow ssh connections via `sudo ufw allow ssh`.

From here, running PuTTY on your host Windows 10 system should only require you to access the IP address `192.168.56.10` via ssh on port 22, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgkfI.png). Hope this helps!